# UISearchController searchBar move down when search is active

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I have presented view controller, which has table view in it.
I have added UISearchController in table header view. When search bar is active, it move down some pixel.I have tried all the options, none are working.

Below my code to add search controller in table view

```
searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self   
searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()   
searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self   
searchController?.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.default   
searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false   
searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false   
searchController?.definesPresentationContext = true  
searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"   
self.otlTableView?.tableHeaderView = searchController?.searchBar
```

I am also attaching screenshots.

[Searchcontroller1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEb0Y.png)

[Searchcontroller2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0yVr.png)